# How to make files safe so users can download and OS will not quarantine them?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I work with Axure software that generates dynamic and navigable prototypes in HTML. Once they are done I need to send a ZIP file of those HTML files to clients via e-mail or any download internal service.

When they open the HTML files nothing works because since they've downloaded it from the internet (or even intranet) Mac OS X marked them with the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute and it's causing a JavaScript error.

I can run this command on Terminal `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine ./` within the folder where the HTML files are located and the issue with JavaScript code is solved.

In other words: Mac OS X is messing up with my prototype HTML files when they are downloaded from the internet and "marked" as suspicious files and quarantined.

My question is: is there a workaround where I can make this files safe (can be a Terminal command or bash script) so I don't need to asks my clients to run a Terminal command every time I send those project files?

Thanks!

Edit: adding important info from Jan's comment: please consider only downloads using Safari.

Comment: Does it also happen when using other download methods? E.g. using Chrome as opposed to Safari, or maybe `curl`?

Comment: Jan, thanks for the question. I've edited the question adding your question: only Safari unfortunately.

Comment: Would you mind a script? What I mean is that you send the script with the zips, and the client can just run the script that will run xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine ./

Comment: This is already a temporary solution. :(